# Как обезопасить сервер от брутфорс авторизации / подбора пароля?

Tags: linux, сервер, безопасность, ssh

Файл `/var/log/messages` забит сообщениями типа:

```
Jun  5 18:41:02 test saslauthd[740]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user=root] [service=] [realm=] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
Jun  5 18:41:06 test saslauthd[741]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user=oracle] [service=] [realm=] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
Jun  5 18:41:07 test saslauthd[741]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user=guest] [service=] [realm=] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
Jun  5 18:41:09 test saslauthd[738]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user=mysql] [service=] [realm=] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
Jun  5 18:41:12 test saslauthd[737]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user=billing] [service=] [realm=] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
```

Я так понимаю, что пытаются подобрать логин/пароль. Но я не могу найти какой IP блочить. Как вычислить IP?

Comment: Ну найдёте вы адрес, и что это даст? Подавляющее большинство пользователей интернета всё равно имеет «серые» (локальные) адреса. Со стороны вашего же сервера виден только «белый» адрес шлюза провайдера. Иными словами, заблокировав IP адрес «злоумышленника», вы с практически стопроцентной вероятностью также заблокируете доступ и всем клиентам того же провайдера в том же районе, в котором он орудовал. Подчёркиваю: *тысячи* людей потеряют возможность *даже заходить* на ваш сайт только потому, что одному человеку, находящемуся за тем же шлюзом, вздумалось взломать его.

Comment: Но временный бан на несколько часов всё равно не помешает

Comment: Посмотрите /var/log/auth.log

Comment: Стопроцентная вероятность блокировки доступа всем клиентам того же провайдера? Глупости!
Десятки и сотни тысяч людей потеряют возможность заходить на сайт? Глупости!
Единственным вариантом, когда эти глупости могут иметь место, это если у провайдера только один ip и всего пара сотен клиентов. :)

Comment: @Arhad вопрос про поиск IP, а не почему это неэффективно.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы! Я сделал tcpdump на всех интерфейсах моего сервера и вычислил 2 IP с которых "работают" хакеры. Уже заблочил через iptables :)

Comment: @Arhad банить надо не ip, а ip + порт (службу) сервера, можно ssh хоть всему интернету забанить, если вы на сервер физически логинитесь с клавиатуры, никто и не заметить

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**апдейт с учетом новой реальности**: 
посмотрите на принятый на днях пакетик законов Яровой, и [попрощайтесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/272207/) с безопасностью ваших пользователей. И ваших серверов. Держитесь там. Здоровья.

1) сканируют вас (обычно) китайские и русские ботнеты, поэтому айпишников будет УЙМА. Увы. Руками вы их не отфильтруете.

Для серверов это не столько *атака* (разовый, не очень долгий всплеск активности с целью взломать/заддосить), сколько постоянная и непрекращающася борьба вашего открытого всему миру сервера с зараженными компьютерами всего мира. Или целыми подсетями (как в моем примере с боевого серва ниже), которые просто принципиально целиком принадлежат *не очень хорошим* людям. Как  вирусы и бактерии для вашего организма. Только у вашего сервера нет иммунной системы :-)

2) прочитайте про  - и поставьте - `fail2ban` - вкратце - он смотрит в логи и при опеределенном количестве неудачных авторизаций временно блокирует ip  в iptables.

3) смените дефолтный порт ssh с 22 на что-нибудь другое, подавляющее большинство ботнетов смотрит на дефолтные порты.

4) *обязательно*  запретите root-доступ к серверу. логиньтесь со своим юзернеймом, подавляющее большинство ботнетов сканит на root-доступ

5) *желательно* (а может и обязательно, смотря насколько вам это важно), уберите возможность логиниться через пароль, только через ssh-ключ. ssh-ключ зашифруйте с паролем и забэкапьте несколько раз - на флэшку или cd.  И спрячьте. В нескольких разных местах - для физической безопасности.

6) если у вас проблемы с текущей властью (в чем я сомневаюсь ) и ваш хостинг находится в России,  ваши проблемы с безопасностью возрастают на порядок, но, в целом, решаемы (до определенных пределов). Впрочем, если у вас успешный бизнес, который можно отжать/убить с помощью доступа к вашим серверам, у вас, скорее всего,  рано или поздно будут проблемы.

- объяснение: небольшая взяточка или угроза и все ваши пароли/данные перехватываются через провайдера связи, через хостера и т.д. условно говоря, доступ к вашим данным может получить любой упорный участковый или [гэбешник](http://www.gazeta.ru/auto/2016/07/02_a_8356667.shtml), которому вы просто не понравились.

и да, tcpdump вам особо не нужен для поиска таких попыток логина. есть /var/log/auth.log, он показывает IP-адреса (собственно, fail2ban и туда тоже смотрит)

вот кусок лога fail2ban:

```
2016-06-06 09:18:07,572 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban 13.76.250.141
#вот сволочь 
2016-06-06 09:24:27,945 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban 121.18.238.19 
2016-06-06 09:25:54,061 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban 139.129.192.152
#подсеть та же
2016-06-06 09:41:23,212 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban 121.18.238.31
2016-06-06 10:03:46,795 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban 58.218.204.32
2016-06-06 10:05:09,915 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban 82.78.247.40
2016-06-06 10:21:53,956 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban 81.198.66.141
2016-06-06 10:22:00,971 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban 114.55.57.177
#неприятные люди
2016-06-06 10:51:44,671 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban 121.18.238.6
2016-06-06 10:56:19,927 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban 58.218.204.80
#снова выходят на связь
2016-06-06 11:38:05,327 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban 121.18.238.6
2016-06-06 11:51:40,250 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban 49.128.240.33
2016-06-06 11:58:28,641 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban 58.218.204.80
2016-06-06 12:17:55,667 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban 116.31.116.35
2016-06-06 12:29:42,528 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban 120.92.4.184
2016-06-06 13:43:36,826 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban 222.186.21.143
2016-06-06 13:47:52,173 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban 5.226.98.21
2016-06-06 13:52:22,402 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban 120.76.76.31
2016-06-06 13:58:11,771 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban 120.76.42.147
2016-06-06 14:24:01,346 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban 221.229.162.7
#и снова те же гости
2016-06-06 14:58:44,162 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban 121.18.238.11
#гвозди бы делать из этих людей, не было б больше этих людей
2016-06-06 15:14:49,197 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban 121.18.238.12
2016-06-06 15:19:49,488 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban 178.239.180.101
2016-06-06 15:22:01,653 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban 188.99.247.231
2016-06-06 15:42:37,835 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Unban 155.133.41.5
```

здесь вы можете видеть, как fail2ban запрещает доступ к порту ssh с айпишников, которые попытались залогиниться несколько раз неудачно.

p.s. fail2ban забанит доступ к порту ssh, а не просто "забанит ip", не ко всем портам, т.е. с этого IP по прежнему можно будет зайти на сайт (порт 80), но при попытке соединиться через ssh на порт 22 - подходящий ip встретит бан в iptables (я к ответам выше, где  пугают "вы не можете банить целые сети")

p.p.s. о ситуации, когда вашу собственную сеть fail2ban забанил на несколько часов:

- это лучше, чем взлом сервера
- залогиньтесь через vpn/с рабочей машины/с мобильного модема
- у облачных сервисов и нормальных хостеров есть интерфейс доступа к серверу через браузер (по сути дела, через браузер вы обращаетесь к `KVM switch`/локальной сети вашего сервера в датацентре, а ее никогда не забанят), и если вам СРОЧНО нужен доступ к ssh, то вы всегда сможете зайти через браузер и разбанить себя.

если вы можете работать с tcpdump/iptables, то сможете настроить и fail2ban

p.p.p.s 
если у вас ubuntu, обязательное: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates - автоматические апдейты софта по безопасности.

p.p.p.p.s.
если вы не просто защищаетесь от ботов и подбора паролей, очень рекомендую попробовать https://github.com/BinaryDefense/artillery

Comment: Я отредактировал заголовок вопроса. Проверьте пожалуйста формулировку.

Comment: Объясните как принятие законов влияет на устойчивость криптографии. Не понимаю каким образом провайдер может осуществить MIM атаку при подключении по SSH.

Comment: fail2ban полная фигня оказалась.... Поясню. Дело в том, что пытался защитить сервер под управлением asterisk и натолкнулся на следующий баг: https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/798
Проблема в конкретной версии, но где гарантии, что в новых версиях тоже не будет подобных траблов?

Comment: > p.p.s. о ситуации, когда вашу собственную сеть fail2ban забанил на несколько часов:

Господа! Есть во-первых белые списки ай-пи адресов. Во-вторых, есть технология VPN... Таким образом можно закрыть ssh от внешнего мира и жить относительно спокойно.

Comment: @gecube это, конечно баг, но я бы не советовал вам никогда полагаться на правила для определенных программ, лучше по портам работать, имхо. слегка сложнее, но надежнее.

Comment: @gecube `> p.p.s. о ситуации, когда вашу собственную сеть fail2ban` буду рад, если вы отредактируете ответ, я писал для людей, которые впервые связались с f2b, примерно также, как кто-нибудь мог бы случайно запретить себе доступ через ssh  к серверу

Comment: @strangeqargo "но я бы не советовал вам никогда полагаться на правила для определенных программ, лучше по портам работать" - не понял какое это имеет отношение. Потому что если разобраться то самое правило, которое не срабатывало, и блочило определенный порт, чтобы злоумышленник не ломился в aster...

Comment: `you can use the two separate jails (asterisk-tcp and asterisk-udp)`  там баг конфига, и `[asterisk] enabled = true` его можно было избежать, насколько я понимаю, настроив фильтрацию руками

Comment: @strangeqargo подчеркну, что там не баг конфига, а баг обработки правил самим f2b. Потом пофиксили (спасибо и на этом). Но осадочек остался. Выводы были сделаны - f2b может сломать правила файрволла, жаль что в *nix сами сервисы не умеют банить злоумышленников (((

Comment: @gecube я думаю, следующее поколение софта этим займется, без нашего вмешательства почти. Мы увидим грандиозные AI-битвы, надеюсь

Comment: P.p.p.s я специально посмотрел и оказалось, что в iptables (точнее в netfilter ядра) тоже есть три или четыре (это очень мало!!!) уязвимости, но вряд ли они серьезные и вряд ли кто-то сможет их применить.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian провайдер-провайдером, а если и хостер и провайдер обязаны сдавать все что можно?

Comment: Часть советов - фигня. Особенная фигня - в слове "обязательно".

Answer (score 8):

Мой собственный опыт - достаточно сменить порт на нестандартный, как подобные записи исчезают практически полностью. Большинство таких записей вызваны от попыток пробиться к вам на сервер на авось. Это как хулиганы, проходящие мимо двери, и наугад дёргающие ручку - а вдруг открыто. Но стоит поместить дверь на 2 метра выше - и никто прыгать к ней не станет. Если образно. А если не образно - то боты как правило не занимаются перебором портов, лишь перебором паролей. Так что самое минимальное что можно сделать, не прибегая к сторонним инструментам - изменить номер порта. Хотя, конечно, если кто-то заинтересуется именно вашим сервером - это не поможет.

Comment: У меня rdp висел на альтернативном порту. Это не помешало просканировать открытые порты шлюза и вскрыть мой rdp.

Comment: @ilyaplot - конечно, я же написал, что если кто-то заинтересуется сервером - то это не поможет. Смысл в том, что подавляющее кол-во ботов, пытающихся подобрать пароль к ssh, перебором портов не занимается. Поэтому они отсеиваются таким простым способом. Но против целенаправленного сканирования одно лишь это конечно же не поможет.

Answer (score 5):

как вариант можно рассмотреть **denyhosts**

Принцип похожий, если будете подключены к базам denyhosts то и превентивно защищены от плохих айпишников.