# Основы безопасности VDS сервера от брут-форса и чека

Tags: безопасность, vds

Здравствуйте.
Недавно просматривал логи VDS сервера за месяц и заметил, что странные сервисы вроде `(p3plcpnl0973.prod.phx3.secureserver.net[72.167.190.2])` каждые N минут пытаются прощупать ssh, proftpd, postfix/smtpd, даже в интерфейс roundcube долбятся. Используют в качестве логина различные вариации названия сайта и почты.
Подскажите, есть ли какие-то стандартные меры безопасности или подробные статьи по отсеиванию вот таких вот "чекеров"?
@Debian Stretch

Comment: [Аналогичный вопрос уже задан и имеет ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/531970/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F)